# why is $\overline{\text{span}\{E_x(C_0(X))\mathbb{C}\}}=\mathbb{C}$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, functions

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, $C_0(X)$ the vector space of complex valued functions vanishing at infinity, endowed with the supremumsnorm. For $x\in X$ consider the evaluation-homomorphism $E_x:C_0(X)\to \mathbb{C},\; g\mapsto g(x).$ I want to know, is $\overline{\text{span}\{E_x(C_0(X))\mathbb{C}\}}=\mathbb{C}$?

I think yes. But I don't know how to prove it in detail. It is $\overline{\text{span}\{E_x(C_0(X))\mathbb{C}\}}=\overline{\text{span} \{ g(x)\lambda;\; g\in C_0(X),\lambda\in\mathbb{C} \} }=\overline{\{\sum\limits_{i=0}^na_i(g(x)\lambda)^i;\; g\in C_0(X),a_i,\lambda\in\mathbb{C},n\in\mathbb{N} \}}$ but now I miss an arguement why this should be $\mathbb{C}$. I appreciate your help. Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Already $E_x(C_0(X))=\mathbb C$. Because given $\lambda\in\mathbb C$, by Uriysohn there exists $f\in C_0(X)$ with $f(x)=\lambda$. Multiplying $\mathbb C$ by all complex numbers and taking linear combinations will still give you $\mathbb C$.